# How do I register a Python DOM object with a javascript engine on initialization?

Tags: javascript, python, dom, javascript-engine

Context:

I'm creating a python application called [itbrowz](https://github.com/AlexisGoodfellow/itbrowz). The ultimate desired outcome of this application is to be a passable modern web browser that can be used directly in iTerm2. For that to happen, I need to integrate an embeddable JavaScript engine into my project.

Legwork I've already done:

The project is using a Python library called [AdvancedHTMLParser](https://github.com/kata198/AdvancedHTMLParser) which (basically) implements the DOM interface in Python. There is also already a local cache containing separate files for all the individual referenced/inline scripts on a given page.

I've been exploring the use of python bindings to various JavaScript engines, such as [v8eval](https://github.com/sony/v8eval). The reason this one doesn't work is that it does not expose a way to register the Python-side document object with the underlying v8 engine, so the JavaScript scripts which expect to manipulate a pre-existing document object will all fail. The same goes for the [spidermonkey](https://github.com/davisp/python-spidermonkey) engine and its associated Python language bindings - there is no way to pass the Python-side DOM to to JavaScript engine's evaluation context.

Problem:

The core issue I'm trying to resolve is the fact that the document object itself is constructed in Python, and so far as I can tell it's not possible to make that Python-side document object available to the JavaScript engine when the engine is initialized. This is the first major problem I need to solve. But even if it were possible to solve the problem of passing the Python-side document object to the JavaScript engine, I'd still need a way to reliably sync the Python-side document object with the newly manipulated state of JavaScript-side document object.

What ideas do you have that could accomplish the goal of registering and syncing a document object over the Python/JavaScript language bridge?

Answer (score 0):

After another long day of research, I've come across something that will address my use case. It is called [Js2Py](https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py). From the README under the "Advanced Usage" heading:

```
"Moreover, you can use Python objects from your JavaScript code if you add them to the scope"
```

This would allow me to patch in the document object I've created in Python into the JavaScript evaluation context. Additionally, it appears that `js2py` offers strong capabilities for transpiling JavaScript files to python files in their entirety through its function `translate_file()`. This could feasibly resolve the cross-language document object syncing issues entirely, since all of the executed code would be in the same language, which means they could share the same document object, and potentially even share the same event loop!

The only downside appears to be the possibility of an intense amount of compute overhead from on-the-fly transpilation from JavaScript to Python. It also appears that the library is currently pre-1.0, so there's likely still some bugs hiding somewhere in the library itself. That being said, it seems like the best option to lean on for a passion project like `itbrowz`.